# Quasar cli command to generate new component

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I would like to know if there's a way to generate new component in quasar by typing some kind of commands.

When using Angular Cli we can generate new component by doing `ng generate component <component name>`

Does Quasar framework have this kind of ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
$ quasar new component MyComponent
```

See the [docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/commands-list) or type `quasar help`.